# I am getting IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Error**

> File "D:/hotel2.py", line 11, in addGuest
>       guests[i].append(name)
>       IndexError: list index out of range

**hotel2.py**

```
def addGuest():
    i = 0
    j = 0
    global guestid
    name = input("Please enter guest name:\n")
    guests[i].append(name)
    guests[j].append(guestid)
    print("Guest %s has been created with guest ID: %d" % (guests[i], guests[j]))
    i += 1
    j += 1
    guestid += 1
```

What I really want to do is store `guestid` and `guestname` in a way that I can display the `guestname` when I enter `guestid`. But this function is not letting me do it.

Comment: sounds like you need a dictionary...

Comment: I don't see a question anywhere here. Did you have a specific request?

Answer (score 2):

You better use dictionary for `key:value` pairs than two lists:

```
guestid2name = {}

def addGuest():
    name = raw_input('enter guest name:\n')
    global guestid
    guestid2name[guestid] = name
    print("Guest %s has been created with guest ID: %d" % (name, guestid))
```

This will create `guestid2name` data structure of guestid's with the guest's name as value. It is much more efficient than using two distinct lists to achieve the same thing.

Comment: And perhaps name this dictionary something more descriptive than `d`, such as `guestid2name`.